# text in Tao Framework with Visual C#

Tags: opengl, text, frameworks, tao-framework

I am working with VS 2013 Community in a C# Windows Form and I am trying out the Tao Framework. My Problem is that I can´t create Text with it, it just appears a white surface with a red cross in it. Could anyonyone tell me what is wrong or how I can manage it?

Here the Example Code:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using Tao.OpenGl; 
using Tao.Platform; 
using Tao.FreeGlut; 

namespace TaoOpenGLTest 
{ 
 public partial class Form1 : Form 
 { 
     int w = 500; 
     int h = 500; 

     public Form1() 
     { 
         InitializeComponent(); 

         this.simpleOpenGlControl1.InitializeContexts(); 

         Gl.glClearDepth(1.0); 
         Gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);       
         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
         Gl.glDepthMask(Gl.GL_TRUE); 
         Gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h); 
         Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION); 
         Gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
         Glu.gluPerspective(45.0f, (double)w / (double)h, 0.01f, 5000.0f); 

         Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_CULL_FACE); 
         Gl.glCullFace(Gl.GL_BACK);           
     } 

     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
     { 
         this.simpleOpenGlControl1.Invalidate(); 
     } 

     private void simpleOpenGlControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
     { 
         Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
         Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW); 
         Gl.glLoadIdentity(); 

         Gl.glTranslated(0, 0, -10); 
         Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINE_LOOP); 
         Gl.glVertex3d(-1, 1, 0); 
         Gl.glVertex3d(-1, -1, 0); 
         Gl.glVertex3d(1, -1, 0); 
         Gl.glVertex3d(1, 1, 0); 
         Gl.glEnd(); 

         Gl.glRasterPos3f(0, 0, 0);    // Set the position for the string (text) 
         text("Text");                      // Display the text "Front"  
     } 

     // Used for the font that will be displayed 
     static void text(string c) 
     { 
         for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++) 
         { 
             // Render bitmap character 
             Glut.glutBitmapCharacter(Glut.GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10, c[i]); 
         } 
     } 

 } 
}
```

Comment: Does your line loop show up? You've translated the z coordinate to **-10.0** which should be clipped. Setting the raster position to `(0.0, 0.0, -10.0)` would also be clipped and that produces undefined results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes the line loop is displayed when I exclude the text() - function. I set the raster position to the upper left corner of the square but there is no improvement. Did you manage that it runs? Do you know another way? Greets hAYX

Comment: Ok, glutInit() was missing!